# nginx client_header_buffer_size Not effective

Tags: node.js, nginx, https

An API service I built is runnig over HTTPS, which has a user get request parameter too long, and then the browser is directly inaccessible, and the parameters in the URL can be shortened.

The server uses the nodejs local test to see how long the parameters can be processed. Finally, it is possible to be a nginx problem, 'cause setting up `client_header_buffer_size` and `large_client_header_buffers`, restarting then nginx, I got the same result.

```
server {
   listen 443 ssl http2;
   listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
   ...
   client_body_buffer_size 600k;
   client_max_body_size 600k;
   client_header_buffer_size 600k;
   large_client_header_buffers 4 600k;
   ...
}
```

Is there anybody in my situation that can provide solutions?

In another case, I used Safari browser to access the URL with a long parameter. Page prompt 303 error? (shortening the web site normal)

Answer (score 0):

From the description of [client_max_body_size](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size), you can set allowed size of the client request body. Try to set it to a max value say

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

or setting it to 0 will remove the check, which is not recommended.

```
client_max_body_size 0;
```